# C++ Insertion Sort crashing

Tags: c++, vector, insertion-sort

I create a vector and fill it with random integers.  I then print out all the unsorted values and call `insertionSort()`.  After this call, the numbers should be printed in sorted order.  My program keeps crashing and I'm not sure why.

Here's my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int listSize;

vector<int> intList()
{
    cout << "How many numbers do you want to sort?\n";
    cin >> listSize;
    vector<int> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    {
        int random = rand() % 10001;
        list.push_back(random);
    }

    return list;
};

void insertionSort(vector<int>& data)
{
    int i, j, tmp;

    for (i = 1; data.size(); i++)
    {
        j = i;
        tmp = data[i];
        while (j > 0 && tmp < data[j-1])
        {
            data[j] = data[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        data[j] = tmp;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    srand(time(0));
    vector<int> list = intList();
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    insertionSort(list);

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: I think [something like this](http://pastebin.com/qaCPV0Rj) would be easier.

Answer (score 5):

This

```
for (i = 1; data.size(); i++)
```

should be:

```
for (i = 1; i<data.size(); ++i)
```

Otherwise the `for` never breaks.

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop doesn't check break condition, and loops forever starting to write out of bounds.

```
for (i = 1; data.size(); i++)
```

You should check if i is smaller than the size of the vector.

```
for (i = 1; i < data.size(); i++)
```